# ipython notebook. Вернуть тему оформления по умолчанию

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Всем добрый день. Решил изменить тему оформления ноутбука. Сделал следующее:
`pip install jupyterthemes`
`jt -t тема оформления`
Тему изменил. Теперь вопрос: Как вернуть обратно тему по умолчанию? Ничего нигде не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вернуть тему, которая была по умолчанию: jt -r